# Can I have two clients (web app + native mobile app) with one client info in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid

I have two client applications : `Asp.Net MVC Core` web app and an `Android` native mobile app, and an `IdentityServer4 Server` as an OpenID Server`.

I know that I have to create two `client` records for both of them (in the `IS4's Clients` table) :

- a `Hybrid Flow` for the web app
- a `Hybrid/Authorization Code + PKCE` for the native mobile app

But I'm wondering if I can create **only one** `Client info` for both of them or not?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create one client definition for each client, so you better can separate them and better evolve them as needed over time. Also makes it easier to separate them in the logs for example.

A question is however why/if you really need to support the hybrid flow? I think both clients only need to use the authorization code flow.

If you want to follow OAuth 2.1, then there are only two flows to use, either authorization code flow or client credentials flow. All other flows are not recommended due to various security issues.  See https://oauth.net/2.1/

Comment: For the second part of your comment, yes you're right, and I think the `authorization code` flow is the best choice, but for the main question, are there any other downsides besides better logging/auditing for separation?

Comment: That's useful, thanks, but I'm looking for some (logical/security perspective) reasons to decide between separating/merging of clients info

Comment: By having separate clients, you can have individual security levels, if needed for example. Or use different signing algorithms if that is needed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Tore's answer gives good reasons to keep those clients separated. If you're still not convinced, I would turn the question around - why do you want to have one logical client data used by two separate clients? This will cause some weird issues in the future. For example, at some point you might want to rate-limit one of those clients, or change client authentication method, or even block one of them completely. You will have to do it for both your apps if you don't create a separate client.

From the security point of view, there is a good reason to keep those two separated: the web client can be a confidential client with a secret assigned. The mobile client will be a public client, without a secret*. This is a solid reason not to mix those two, as you will lower the strength of your security considerably.

*In fact, best practice would be to use [DCR](https://curity.io/resources/learn/authenticated-dcr-example/) and register a new client for each device where your app runs.